# What are the two original bigrams for 拥戴 if the do exists

Tags: characters

"拥戴" is probably a condensed version of two other bigrams, however I couldn't figure them out.

Maybe someone out there can help me with this.

谢谢

Comment: Please don’t create new tags without carefully thinking about your question and trying to understand and fit the question into existing tags.

Comment: I would have thought that a bigrams tag would make perfectly sense. Believe me I thought this through;-)

Comment: Would it be "擁戴" you are looking for? 拥 is the simplified 擁.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding they are 拥护 and 爱戴.